# Best T1 terminating router

Tags: router

Folks!
My network has a CISCO 2611 Router which is used to terminate a T1 connection.  An ethernet cable then goes from the T1 to a SonicWall's WAN port.  I would like to replace the CISCO 2611 Router with another router that is easier to configure and manage (preferably with a Web page or a GUI interface).  Which router would you recommend?  The T1's upstream and downstream sped is 1.536 Mbps and it is supporting a block of 16 IP addresses.  Thanks, in advance, for your help. - Charles

Comment: Is there anything actually wrong with the 2611 ? features you need that it can't support? It not being able to keep up with the data rate? Unstable?

Comment: The firewall has sent me these messages "WAN Availability - Probing failure on NAT Static IP" and "WAN Availability - WLB Resource failed".  I have received these messages on three occasions in the last two days, where it couldn't find 4.2.2.2.  I don't know if it's a problem with my router, T1 service or the destination.  I'm just trying to be prepared in case we might have to change the router.  Thanks!

Comment: A google search for [WAN Availability - Probing failure on NAT Static IP](http://www.google.com/search?q=WAN+Availability+-+WLB+Resource+failed) seems to imply that you are getting a message from a sonicwall appliance, not a Cisco router.  Are you sure you are looking at the correct device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend the Cisco 2611, or another device in the same general family.  Cisco make s a fine router, the units are very common, and reasonably well-liked.  Sticking with Cisco hardware (or if you're sure you want to change, another major vendor like [Juniper](http://www.juniper.net/)) will make it easier to find qualified network admins if/when you need to grow your network in the future.

There are GUI tools available for most Cisco devices -- for example, the [Cisco Configuration Assistant (CCA)](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps7287/index.html).  Contact Cisco for information on tools available for your specific router.

Comment: 2611 is EOL now ... today i'd recommend the 800 series

Comment: @Zypher - really? Wow, it's been a very long time since I went near Cisco hardware.  Something still supported then, by all means - but i'd stay with Cisco or Juniper if at all possible.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and suggestions, @voretag7 and @Zypher!  I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you find hard to manage with Cisco router? Also do you use any dynamic routing protocols, etc. If not - then what exactly requires configuration? Typically you can just "set and forget"

I also find cisco configurations very easy and pragmatic. I have a similar routers and a Watchguard firewall which has a GUI configuration tool. I just can't stand it - the configuration tool runs only on Windows, it's confusing, it is has way less features than a similar cisco firewall. So I suggest you take some time to learn how to use IOS. It's quite easy for basic tasks.